# Assign a dynamic function to Global Environment in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables

This question will be a **simple** one for some members of this forum, but I am expending a lot of time searching for an answer and I did not find any working one. 
Let me clarify: I have a simple function that conducts a linear regression, and the results become a variable and this variable is assigned to the global environment. Straightforward method.

However, every time I run this function, the variable is replaced, what I don't want. 
I just want to define a specific name instead of replacing this variable.

Please check out this code to understand my question:

```
set.seed(123)
ds <- data.frame(income=rnorm(1000,700,20), sex=c(0,1), age=rnorm(1000,30,10))

regress <- function(iv_string) {
  regression_formula <- as.formula(paste("income ~", iv_string))
  results <<- lm(regression_formula, ds)
  plot(results)
  print(results)
}
regress("age")
regress("sex")
```

Something like that

```
  regress <- function(iv_string, **custom_name**) {
      regression_formula <- as.formula(paste("income ~", iv_string))
      results[**custom_name**] <<- lm(regression_formula, ds)
      plot(results)
      print(results)
    }
regress("sex","sex_on_income") #this model will be used in other analysis, once it will be assigned at global environment
regress("age","age_on_income") #this model will be used !!
```

[image: final solution]
Thanks much.

Comment: You should `return` the value from the function and assign it outside the function. `<<-` is not a good way to do what you are trying here

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will write the `lm` object out to the parent frame or other environment specified by `env`, plot it, print it and invisibly return it.   Also we make sure that the formula's environment is `env` which allows iv_string to refer to objects in `env` as well as columns in `ds`.  (If we knew that `iv_string` only referred to column names in `ds` then we could just use `fo <- paste("income ~", iv_string)` as `lm` will accept character strings as formulas.)  We use `do.call(...)` to ensure that the `lm` output shows the actual formula rather than just `fo`.  We used the parent frame as the default for `env` which is more usual but if you really want the default to be the global environment replace `parent.frame()` with `.GlobalEnv` or with`globalenv()`.

```
regress <- function(iv_string, custom_name = iv_string, env = parent.frame()) {
  fo <- as.formula(paste("income ~", iv_string), env)
  env[[custom_name]] <- results <- do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(ds)))
  plot(results)
  print(results)
  invisible(results)
}

regress("age", "lm_age")
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = income ~ age, data = ds)  <-- note that formula shows, not just fo

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          age  
   695.1540       0.1699
```

That said, the normal style in R is not to write objects out to the parent frame or to the global environment but to return them:

```
regress <- function(iv_string, env = parent.frame()) {
  fo <- as.formula(paste("income ~", iv_string), env)
  results <- do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(ds)))
  plot(results)
  print(results)
  invisible(results)
}

lm_age <- regress("age")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I appreciate the additional information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code that I *think* gives you what you want.

```
regress <- function(iv_string, custom_name) {
  regression_formula <- as.formula(paste("income ~", iv_string))
  assign(custom_name, lm(regression_formula, ds), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  plot(get(custom_name))
  print(get(custom_name))
}

regress("age", "age_reg")
```

In the code above, I `assign` the regression results to a global variable defined by the string `custom_name`. For the `plot` and `print` statements, I use `get` to get the variable named in that string and pass it to those functions. So, in my example, it'll create the plots and print the results and a variable called `age_reg` will appear in the global environment and contain the regression results.

Comment: I dont think this is a good answer.  There is no apparent reason OP should need to assign to global environemtn like this rather than returning the result from the function and doing the assignment outside

Comment: @dww Yup, I agree.